# useEffect update the state but the not the const related to the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-effect

Hi I've got a problem that I don't understrand : when I look the web tools I can see that my state is update with the useEffect and some of the const related to that state are update but not all of them.

This my code

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'

import Entete from './MEP/entete'
import OADMenu from './MEP/oadMenu'
import GraphMarges from './Graphiques/marges'


function RisquesPrix() {
  const { state } = useLocation()
  const { city } = state

  const [PBTot, setPBTot]= React.useState(0);

  useEffect ( () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000//api/1.0/page/exploitation/1789')
    .then( (response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(response =>{
      setPBTot(response.PBTotal)
      
    }) 
  }, [])

  const ChargesTot = PBTot*0.85

  const ventes2Moins = [{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*0.98},{x:6,y:PBTot*0.96},{x:9,y:PBTot*0.94},{x:12,y:PBTot*0.91},{x:18,y:PBTot*0.89}]
  const ventesMoins = [{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:6,y:PBTot*0.985},{x:9,y:PBTot*0.975},{x:12,y:PBTot*0.97},{x:18,y:PBTot*0.955}]
  const ventesMoy = [{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*1.01},{x:6,y:PBTot*1.02},{x:9,y:PBTot*1.04},{x:12,y:PBTot*1.05},{x:18,y:PBTot*1.07}]
  const ventesPlus = [{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*1.02},{x:6,y:PBTot*1.05},{x:9,y:PBTot*1.07},{x:12,y:PBTot*1.08},{x:18,y:PBTot*1.12}]
  const ventes2Plus = [{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*1.04},{x:6,y:PBTot*1.09},{x:9,y:PBTot*1.10},{x:12,y:PBTot*1.13},{x:18,y:PBTot*1.17}]
  
  const charges2Moins = [{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*0.96},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*0.94},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*0.92},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*0.89},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*0.87}]
  const chargesMoins = [{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*0.99},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*0.985},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*0.97},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*0.965},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*0.95}]
  const chargesMoy = [{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*1.01},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*1.02},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*1.04},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*1.05},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*1.07}]
  const chargesPlus = [{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*1.05},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*1.08},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*1.10},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*1.11},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*1.15}]
  const charges2Plus = [{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*1.08},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*1.13},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*1.15},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*1.17},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*1.19}]

  const [Pvente, setPV]= React.useState(ventesMoy)
  const [ChargesF, setC]= React.useState(chargesMoy)

  const [BV2M, setBV2M]= React.useState('UnChecked')
  const [BVM, setBVM]= React.useState('UnChecked')
  const [BVMoy, setBVMoy]= React.useState('Checked')
  const [BVP, setBVP]= React.useState('UnChecked')
  const [BV2P, setBV2P]= React.useState('UnChecked')

  const [BC2M, setBC2M]= React.useState('UnChecked')
  const [BCM, setBCM]= React.useState('UnChecked')
  const [BCMoy, setBCMoy]= React.useState('Checked')
  const [BCP, setBCP]= React.useState('UnChecked')
  const [BC2P, setBC2P]= React.useState('UnChecked')

  const maximum= ventes2Plus[7].y
  const minimum= charges2Moins[7].y  
  
  function handlePressV2M() {
    setPV(ventes2Moins)
    setBV2M('Checked')

    setBVM('UnChecked')
    setBVMoy('UnChecked')
    setBVP('UnChecked')
    setBV2P('UnChecked')

  }
  function handlePressVM() {
    setPV(ventesMoins)
    setBVM('Checked')

    setBV2M('UnChecked')
    setBVMoy('UnChecked')
    setBVP('UnChecked')
    setBV2P('UnChecked')

  }
  function handlePressVMoy() {
    setPV(ventesMoy)
    setBVMoy('Checked')

    setBV2M('UnChecked')
    setBVM('UnChecked')
    setBVP('UnChecked')
    setBV2P('UnChecked')

  }
  function handlePressVP() {
    setPV(ventesPlus)
    setBVP('Checked')

    setBV2M('UnChecked')
    setBVM('UnChecked')
    setBVMoy('UnChecked')
    setBV2P('UnChecked')

  }
  function handlePressV2P() {
    setPV(ventes2Plus)
    setBV2P('Checked')

    setBV2M('UnChecked')
    setBVM('UnChecked')
    setBVMoy('UnChecked')
    setBVP('UnChecked')

  }

  function handlePressC2M() {
    setC(charges2Moins)
    setBC2M('Checked')

    setBCM('UnChecked')
    setBCMoy('UnChecked')
    setBCP('UnChecked')
    setBC2P('UnChecked')

  }
  function handlePressCM() {
    setC(chargesMoins)
    setBCM('Checked')

    setBC2M('UnChecked')
    setBCMoy('UnChecked')
    setBCP('UnChecked')
    setBC2P('UnChecked')

  }
  function handlePressCMoy() {
    setC(chargesMoy)
    setBCMoy('Checked')

    setBC2M('UnChecked')
    setBCM('UnChecked')
    setBCP('UnChecked')
    setBC2P('UnChecked')

  }
  function handlePressCP() {
    setC(chargesPlus)
    setBCP('Checked')

    setBC2M('UnChecked')
    setBCM('UnChecked')
    setBCMoy('UnChecked')
    setBC2P('UnChecked')
  }

  function handlePressC2P() {
    setC(charges2Plus)
    setBC2P('Checked')

    setBC2M('UnChecked')
    setBCM('UnChecked')
    setBCMoy('UnChecked')
    setBCP('UnChecked')

  }
  return (
    <div >
      <Entete titre="Risques prix"/>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='titre'>Quel est l’impact de l’évolution du prix sur ma marge ? {city} </div>
          <div className='paragraphe'>Les prix de vente et les charges connaissent de fortes variations. Estimez l'impact sur votre marge.  </div>

          <div className='card cardPrix'>
              <div className='titreCard'>Sélectionnez des variations de charges et de prix de vente </div>

              <div className='flexLigne'>
                <div style={{fontSize:25, textAlign:'right', width:'25%', }}>Prix de vente</div>
                <button className={BV2M==='UnChecked' ? 'buttonPrix buttonPrixDefault' : 'buttonPrix buttonPrixChecked'} onClick={handlePressV2M}  >
                  <div className='active'>--</div>
                </button>
                <button className={BVM==='UnChecked' ? 'buttonPrix buttonPrixDefault' : 'buttonPrix buttonPrixChecked'} onClick={handlePressVM}  >
                  <div className='active'>-</div>
                </button>
                <button className={BVMoy==='UnChecked' ? 'buttonPrix buttonPrixDefault' : 'buttonPrix buttonPrixChecked'} onClick={handlePressVMoy}  >
                  <div className='active2'>Moy</div>
                </button>
                <button className={BVP==='UnChecked' ? 'buttonPrix buttonPrixDefault' : 'buttonPrix buttonPrixChecked'} onClick={handlePressVP}  >
                  <div className='active'>+</div>
                </button>
                <button className={BV2P==='UnChecked' ? 'buttonPrix buttonPrixDefault' : 'buttonPrix buttonPrixChecked'} onClick={handlePressV2P}  >
                  <div className='active'>++</div>
                </button>
              </div>

              <div className='flexLigne'>
                <div style={{fontSize:25, textAlign:'right', width:'25%',}}>Charges</div>
                <button className={BC2M==='UnChecked' ? 'buttonPrix buttonPrixDefault' : 'buttonPrix buttonPrixChecked'} onClick={handlePressC2M}  >
                  <div className='active'>--</div>
                </button>
                <button className={BCM==='UnChecked' ? 'buttonPrix buttonPrixDefault' : 'buttonPrix buttonPrixChecked'} onClick={handlePressCM}  >
                  <div className='active'>-</div>
                </button>
                <button className={BCMoy==='UnChecked' ? 'buttonPrix buttonPrixDefault' : 'buttonPrix buttonPrixChecked'} onClick={handlePressCMoy}  >
                  <div className='active2'>Moy</div>
                </button>
                <button className={BCP==='UnChecked' ? 'buttonPrix buttonPrixDefault' : 'buttonPrix buttonPrixChecked'} onClick={handlePressCP}  >
                  <div className='active'>+</div>
                </button>
                <button className={BC2P==='UnChecked' ? 'buttonPrix buttonPrixDefault' : 'buttonPrix buttonPrixChecked'} onClick={handlePressC2P}  >
                  <div className='active'>++</div>
                </button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div className='titreMoins'>Résultats</div>
          <div className='paragraphe'>Les résultats sont exprimés en  milliers d'euros. "12" corresponds à une échéance dans 12 mois (dans 1 an) et "-3", celle d'il y a 3 mois. </div>
          <GraphMarges dataPrix={Pvente} dataCharges={ChargesF} maximum={maximum} minimum={minimum}/>
          <div className='legend'>
            <div className='legendBloc'>
              <div className='legendGraphiquePrix legendcharges'>|</div>
              <div className='paragraphe'>Charges</div>
            </div>
            <div className='legendBloc'>
              <div className='legendGraphiquePrix legendventes'>|</div>
              <div className='paragraphe'>Prix de vente</div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div className='titreMoins'>Projections de la marge et son incertitude</div>

          <div className='flexLignePrix'>
            <div className='blocPrix'>
              <div className='videBlocPrix videBloc3'>
                <div className='pleinBlocPrix pleinBloc3'>
                  <div className='titreBloc'>3 mois</div>
                </div>
                <div style={{marginBottom:13}}>
                  <div className='paragrapheBlocPrix paragrapheBloc3'> {Math.round(Pvente[3].y-ChargesF[3].y).toLocaleString()}€ </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='blocPrix'>
              <div className='videBlocPrix videBloc6'>
                <div className='pleinBlocPrix pleinBloc6'>
                  <div className='titreBloc'>6 mois</div>
                </div>
                <div style={{marginBottom:13}}>
                  <div className='paragrapheBlocPrix paragrapheBloc6'>{Math.round(Pvente[4].y-ChargesF[4].y).toLocaleString()}€</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='blocPrix'>
              <div className='videBlocPrix videBloc9'>
                <div className='pleinBlocPrix pleinBloc9'>
                  <div className='titreBloc'>9 mois</div>
                </div>
                <div style={{marginBottom:13}}>
                  <div className='paragrapheBlocPrix paragrapheBloc9'>{Math.round(Pvente[5].y-ChargesF[5].y).toLocaleString()}€</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div className='blocPrix'>
              <div className='videBlocPrix videBloc12'>
                <div className='pleinBlocPrix pleinBloc12'>
                  <div className='titreBloc'>12 mois</div>
                </div>
                <div style={{marginBottom:13}}>
                  <div className='paragrapheBlocPrix paragrapheBloc12'>{Math.round(Pvente[6].y-ChargesF[6].y).toLocaleString()}€</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='blocPrix'>
              <div className='videBlocPrix videBloc18'>
                <div className='pleinBlocPrix pleinBloc18'>
                  <div className='titreBloc'>18 mois</div>
                </div>
                <div style={{marginBottom:13}}>
                  <div className='paragrapheBlocPrix paragrapheBloc18'>{Math.round(Pvente[7].y-ChargesF[7].y).toLocaleString()}€</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <OADMenu city={city}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RisquesPrix;
```

And this is my states an data when their are past to an other component :

```js
{
  "dataPrix": [
    "{x: -6, y: 0}",
    "{x: -3, y: 0}",
    "{x: 0, y: 0}",
    "{x: 3, y: 0}",
    "{x: 6, y: 0}",
    "{x: 9, y: 0}",
    "{x: 12, y: 0}",
    "{x: 18, y: 0}"
  ], //[{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*1.01},{x:6,y:PBTot*1.02},{x:9,y:PBTot*1.04},{x:12,y:PBTot*1.05},{x:18,y:PBTot*1.07}]
  "dataCharges": [
    "{x: -6, y: 0}",
    "{x: -3, y: 0}",
    "{x: 0,y: 0}",
    "{x: 3, y: 0}",
    "{x: 6, y: 0}",
    "{x: 9, y: 0}",
    "{x: 12, y: 0}",
    "{x: 18, y: 0}"
  ], //[{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*1.01},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*1.02},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*1.04},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*1.05},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*1.07}]
  "maximum": 190188.18, // const maximum= ventes2Plus[7].y
  "minimum": 120208.68299999999 //const minimum= charges2Moins[7].y 
}
```

So maximum is the right data but not the data that is suppose to be put in a chart.
But when I click again on "Moy" the data appear.

Can someone help me understand ?

Comment: add setPBTot to the list dependencies of useEffect, useEffect(() => {}, [setPBTot]) and maybe create your functions as useCallbacks could be a good approach

Comment: I'm going to try that thanks

Comment: I think I don't understand where you think I use the useCallback. Because I try it on the const ventesMoy and chargesMoy but it did nothing. Also I can't call ti on the state declaration so....

Comment: no, I mean you doun'0t use them, instead of function handlePressV2M() ... try it like const handlePressV2M = useCallback(() => {...}, [setPV, set...])

Comment: @EdwynZN
 it doesn't work, because I need to put the date to updtae the state and I've got this warning : The 'ventesMoy' array makes the dependencies of useCallback Hook (at line 89) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the initialization of 'ventesMoy' in its own useMemo() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problème was that the state PBTot is initialize on 0 so the const was calculate based on this 0. So at the begining all the ste was in 0 based but not the const that is instantly updting. I get arround of the problème by checking if it was the first the time the component mount:

- if it is the case, the data take the value of a const
- if it's not, the date take the state.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'

import Entete from './MEP/entete'
import OADMenu from './MEP/oadMenu'
import GraphMarges from './Graphiques/marges'


function RisquesPrix() {
  const { state } = useLocation()
  const { city } = state

  const [PBTot, setPBTot]= React.useState();
  const [Mount, setMount] = React.useState(true);
  const [Mount2, setMount2] = React.useState(true);

  
  useEffect ( () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/1.0/page/exploitation/1789')
    .then( (response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(response =>{
      setPBTot(response.PBTotal)
      setPBTot(prev => {
        return prev;
      })
    }) 
  }, [setPBTot])

  const ChargesTot = PBTot*0.85

  const ventes2Moins = [{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*0.98},{x:6,y:PBTot*0.96},{x:9,y:PBTot*0.94},{x:12,y:PBTot*0.91},{x:18,y:PBTot*0.89}] 
  const ventesMoins = [{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:6,y:PBTot*0.985},{x:9,y:PBTot*0.975},{x:12,y:PBTot*0.97},{x:18,y:PBTot*0.955}]
  const ventesMoy = [{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*1.01},{x:6,y:PBTot*1.02},{x:9,y:PBTot*1.04},{x:12,y:PBTot*1.05},{x:18,y:PBTot*1.07}]
  const ventesPlus = [{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*1.02},{x:6,y:PBTot*1.05},{x:9,y:PBTot*1.07},{x:12,y:PBTot*1.08},{x:18,y:PBTot*1.12}]
  const ventes2Plus = [{x:-6,y:PBTot*0.99},{x:-3,y:PBTot*0.995},{x:0,y:PBTot},{x:3,y:PBTot*1.04},{x:6,y:PBTot*1.09},{x:9,y:PBTot*1.10},{x:12,y:PBTot*1.13},{x:18,y:PBTot*1.17}]
  
  const charges2Moins = [{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*0.96},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*0.94},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*0.92},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*0.89},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*0.87}]
  const chargesMoins = [{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*0.99},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*0.985},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*0.97},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*0.965},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*0.95}]
  const chargesMoy = [{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*1.01},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*1.02},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*1.04},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*1.05},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*1.07}]
  const chargesPlus = [{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*1.05},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*1.08},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*1.10},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*1.11},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*1.15}]
  const charges2Plus = [{x:-6,y:ChargesTot*0.95},{x:-3,y:ChargesTot*0.98},{x:0,y:ChargesTot},{x:3,y:ChargesTot*1.08},{x:6,y:ChargesTot*1.13},{x:9,y:ChargesTot*1.15},{x:12,y:ChargesTot*1.17},{x:18,y:ChargesTot*1.19}]

  const [Pvente, setPV]= React.useState(ventesMoy)
  const [ChargesF, setC]= React.useState(chargesMoy)
  const Pvente2 = ventesMoy
  const ChargesF2 = chargesMoy
.....
 function handlePressV2M() {
    setPV(ventes2Moins)
    setBV2M('Checked')

    setBVM('UnChecked')
    setBVMoy('UnChecked')
    setBVP('UnChecked')
    setBV2P('UnChecked')

    setMount(false)
  }
.....
 function handlePressC2M() {
    setC(charges2Moins)
    setBC2M('Checked')

    setBCM('UnChecked')
    setBCMoy('UnChecked')
    setBCP('UnChecked')
    setBC2P('UnChecked')

    setMount2(false)
  }

...
<GraphMarges dataPrix={Mount?Pvente2: Pvente} dataCharges={Mount2?ChargesF2:ChargesF} maximum={maximum} minimum={minimum}/>

.....
```